# An isoperimetric inequality for a Hamming sphere

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Let $S$ be a subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ such that every element of $S$ has weight (the number of $1$-coordinates) $k$ (may be not all elements with such weight belong to $S$).

Denote by $S_r$ the $r$-boundary of $S$ i.e. the set of elements $y$ such that there is $x$ in $S$ such that  the Hamming distance between $x$ and $y$ is at most $r$. (The set $S$ itself belongs to $S_r$.)

> Question: How small can be the cardinality of $S_r$ depend on $|S|$, $k$ and $r$?

Comment: Please clarify: is $S$ the set of *all* points that have weight $k$, or just some such points?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen some such points

Comment: Still unclear. All vectors of weight $k$ or not? "the subset of.." vs "a subset of.." would clarify the question. Also do you include points in $S$ itself in the $r-$boundary?

Comment: @kodlu 1) a subset of.

Comment: @kodlu 2) Yes, I include points in $S$ in the $r$-boundary.

Comment: thanks, included the text in the question body

Comment: I don't quite see what makes this question isoperimetric ("having the same perimeter"). To me it seems like a coding theory / ball packing question. If the points in $S$ are far apart, $S_r$ consists of $|S|$ disjoint $r$-radius balls. If the points are closer, the balls can intersect. At the extreme where $|S|$ contains all points of weight $k$ the answer is particularly simple. What is the regime of interest? Points far apart or close together?